# How to make this if statement more elegant?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, sqldatareader

If `x` is equal to `1` then we need the `SqlDataReader` from `GetDataReader1` method. Otherwise, we need `SqlDataReader` from `GetDataReader2`. That is the only difference. Other than that, all the code needed (where it says do stuff here) is going to be duplicated. How can I make this more elegant so I don't have to repeat all the logic within both using statements?

**Update:** In simplifying the code for this post, I missed an additional factor. GetDataReader1 takes 2 parameters and GetDataReader2 takes 3 parameters. If I create one GetDataReader function, and move the `If` statement there, will I be forced to pass in the extra parameter that is currently not needed for the GetDataReader1 method?

```
Dim value1, value2, value3 As String

If x = 1 Then
    Using myDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader1(value1, value2)
        myDataReader.Read()
        If myDataReader.HasRows Then
            'do stuff here
        End If
     End Using
 Else
     Using myDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader2(value1, value2, value3)
         myDataReader.Read()
         If myDataReader.HasRows Then
             'do stuff here
         End If
     End Using
 End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in `x` to `GetDataReader` and let **it** determine what to return.

```
Using myDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader(x)
    myDataReader.Read()
    If myDataReader.HasRows Then
        'do stuff here
    End If
End Using
```

This pushes the `If` into `GetDataReader` where your shouldn't have much duplication.

---

Update - following update on the question.

You can still use the same mechanism - pushing the decision to a method - you simply need to pass in all the parameters that may be needed in addition to `x`:

```
Using myDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader(x, value1, value2, value3)
```

Comment: :- Correct me if I am wrong. Cant we create a simple function and call that to avoid redundance?

Comment: @RahulTripathi - That's pretty much what I did.

Comment: GetDataReader1 and GetDataReader2 would need to become GetDataReader that takes a parameter of an integer?

Comment: Yes, Thats what I was trying to make out. :)

Comment: @kush - Or whatever the type of `x` is.

Comment: Is it correct that in my head I read **it** in the first sentence of your answer as `x`?

Comment: @kush - **it** refers to the `GetDataReader` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my update. Sorry I forgot to mention an additional factor.

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic for determining which SqlDataReader to use into its own function and pass it `x`.

```
    Using myDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader(x)
         myDataReader.Read()
         If myDataReader.HasRows Then
             'do stuff here
         End If
     End Using

 Private Function GetDataReader(ByVal x As Integer) As SqlDataReader
     If x = 1 Then
        Return GetDataReader1()
     Else
        Return GetDataReader2()
     End If
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the readers in the Using-statement. Create them before

```
Dim value1, value2, value3 As String
Dim myDataReader As SqlDataReader

If x = 1 Then
    myDataReader = GetDataReader1(value1, value2)
Else
    myDataReader = GetDataReader2(value1, value2, value3)
End If
Using myDataReader
    If myDataReader.Read() Then
        'do stuff here
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: `GetDataReader1` and `GetDataReader2` have a `SqlDataReader` that gets returned (`Return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)`). If I call these methods outside the `Using` statement, will the SqlConnection still get closed when `myDataReader` is closed?

Comment: Yes. The `Using`-statement always calls the `Dispose` method of the objects passed to it, even if an error should occur or if you leave the using block with a `Return` for instance.